# Best way to add database calls to OO PHP

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I am writing a new website that uses PHP and MySQL. I am trying to do this using OO and would welcome a bit of advice.

I know that I should structure the class as follows but what I am not sure about is whether I should create separate methods for accessing the database to insert, update etc. the name.

Does it matter? Should I have separate methods or can I just roll the code into set_name and get_name?

```
<?php  

class person { 

 var $name;  

  function set_name($new_name) {  

  $this->name = $new_name;   

 } 

 function get_name() { 

  return $this->name;  
 }  

}  
?>
```

Comment: You'd need your db calls in a model and yes they'd need to be separate for insert, select, update etc.

Comment: @SpaceBeers You wouldnt need different functions for update & insert. You could write a function like save() which checks if the record exists, if it does update else insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in [Object-relation-mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) and/or specifically the [Active Record Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) as a starter. See also [this example](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Using-the-Active-Record-Pattern-with-PHP-and-MySQL/1/) for a implementation.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice. I think that this is the one that most closely matches what I was looking for so I will accept.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use php5?

Look in the direction of ready-made solutions, for example Doctrine-ORM or other ORM engine.

Answer (score 0):

You basically should not care about your concrete database. The `Person` class should not care at all how or even if ever it is stored somewhere.

Just keep the things apart. E.g. for starters you create a `ObjectMockStorage` class that has a `store` and `retrieve` method.

These methods can decide by the object you pass in what should happen with that object.

You can then just create your application and until you actually need storage (maybe not even MySQL who knows already today?), you can change the type of the `Storage` to something different with the same [interface](http://php.net/interface).

This also helps you to get your application more quickly running and actually not wasting time in caring about things you don't yet need to care about.